# Write into S3 on LocalStack with Spark 3: RemoteFileChangedException - Change reported by S3 during open at position. ETag was unavailable

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-s3, testcontainers, localstack

I am trying to write parquet into S3 in my testcontainers Localstack and get this error:

```
org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.RemoteFileChangedException: open `s3a://***.snappy.parquet': Change reported by S3 during open at position ***. ETag *** was unavailable
```

It is working with real S3 and it worked with Spark 2.4 and Hadoop 2.7.

I am using: Scala 2.12.15, Spark 3.2.1, hadoop-aws 3.3.1, testcontainers-scala-localstack 0.40.8

The code is very simple, just write dataframe into s3 location:

```
val path = "s3a://***"
import spark.implicits._

val df = Seq(UserRow("1", List("10", "20"))).toDF()
df.write.parquet(path)
```

Comment: Can you share more code or an reproducer?

Comment: @KevinWittek added to question description

Comment: i could answer it, but instead iI'm going to say "why don't you paste the exception into google and say "follow the link in s3a troublshooting and read what it says". as someone who wrote a lot of that documentation I find ir really disappointing when people ask for help on SO without seemingly searching for the error.

Comment: @stevel I found only one link but it doesn't help me https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/troubleshooting_s3a.html

Comment: oh it does. search for the message. https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/troubleshooting_s3a.html#RemoteFileChangedException_and_read-during-overwrite

Comment: @stevel I can search, can you imagine? But that information doen't help to solve my issue

Comment: you are working with a third party store, aren't you? in which case the "third party store" comment applies

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution for this issue?

Comment: @RudyVerboven no :( just downgraded Spark to some version (don't remember which one)

Answer (score 1):

You could disable bucket versioning at the moment when you create it.
Here is an example:

```
      //create an S3 client using localstack container
       S3Client s3Client = S3Client.builder ()
        .endpointOverride (localStackContainer.getEndpointOverride (LocalStackContainer.Service.S3))
        .credentialsProvider (StaticCredentialsProvider.create (AwsBasicCredentials
            .create (localStackContainer.getAccessKey (), localStackContainer.getSecretKey ())))
        .region (Region.of (localStackContainer.getRegion ()))
        .build ();
        

    // create desired bucket
    s3Client.createBucket (builder -> builder.bucket (<your-bucket-name>));


    //disable versioning on your bucket
    s3Client.putBucketVersioning (builder -> builder
        .bucket (<your-bucket-name>)
        .versioningConfiguration (builder1 -> builder1
            .status (BucketVersioningStatus.SUSPENDED)));
```

Comment: sounds like a plan but unfortunately it doesn't help :(